# Make sure the iframe is loaded and exist in the page

Tags: javascript

I have an iFrame and I want to execute one of its functions from the parent so I wrote this:

```
const messenger_iFrame = $(`iframe[src*='url of iframe']`);
messenger_iFrame.attr("id","messengerID"); // adding an ID to the iframe in order to selecting it
document.getElementById('messengerID').contentWindow.iFrameFunc(); // initiate the iframe function
```

The above code works fine **most of the time** that's because sometimes when I run the code the iframe doesn't fully load and I get the this is not the function error.

What is your solution?

How can I find out the iframe is loaded and exist in the page before I run this code?

I think maybe we can execute another function from inside the iframe and ...

this code won't work for me because if the iframe is not in the page I can't select it like this... it only works to find out all the elements inside iframe is loaded:

```
$('iframe').on('load', function() {
    // do stuff 
});
```

Again when there is no iframe in the page yet (because it still has not been loaded) you can not select it like the above code.

Comment: you have to use iframe load event...

Comment: Please, guys, it won't work for me... please reopen the question..

Comment: it is still unclear, you say that the page does not know that it has an iframe present? that does not make sense!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // your code });`. This way you can make sure your code is triggered after the page has loaded.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Comment: Based on your reference subframes are not loaded yet when this listener executes... so your answer won't work...